# jquery / knockout.js and returning a filtered array of new objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, knockout.js

Is there a way to return a filtered list of new objects with knockout.js or jquery.  I want to return a list of items that have IsSelected and create a new object from it, otherwise I dont want to return it.

```
return ko.utils.arrayForEach(result.items, function (item) {
    if (item.IsSelected)
        return {};
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have you looked here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html

Comment: For what?  That doesnt say how to filter an array and return a new list of new objects.

Comment: Correct, but it will populate the target of selectedOptions with the selected items. It is a separate array from the one that is populating the list and, if I'm understanding your request correctly, shouldn't need any more filtering.

Comment: Look at the answers below, they have the right idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your answers helped out.  I did this below.

```
result.selected = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(getSelectedItems(result.items()), function (item) {
            return { Id: item.Id };
        });
    }, result);


    function getSelectedItems(items) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(items, function (item) {
            return item.IsSelected();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use JQuery's `filter()` function:

```
return $(result.items).filter(function() {
  return this.IsSelected;
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Better yet, you can use `grep()` (See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
var arr = $.grep(result.items, function(item) {
  return item.IsSelected;
});
return arr.length > 0 ? arr : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.grep will iterate an array and return an array based on your criteria. Then you would need to iterate this array and clone() the objects to get your desired result.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

```
var arr = [{foo:1, bar: 2}, {foo: 2 , bar: 3}, {foo: 10, bar: 2}];
var x = jQuery.grep(arr, function (item, i) {
    return item.foo < 5;
});
//x = [{foo:1, bar:2}, {foo: 2, bar: 3}]

var y = [];
// here is the create a new object part
// clone your objects (you could use jQuery.clone() if they are elements).
x.each(function (item) {
   y.push(jQuery.extend({}, $(this)));
});
```